# How to get an item from an array of objects stored in Vuex by ID field?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have an array of objects in a `Vuex` store. Like this:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    value: 'some value'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    value: 'other value'
  },
  ...
]
```

Is there a way to create a getter to get a certain item of the array by `id`?

Something like

```
getArrItem(state, id) {
  return state.find(item => item.id === id);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [method-style-access](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#method-style-access) as follows :

```
getArrItem: (state) => (id) => {
  return state.items.find(item => item.id === id);
}
```